# Angular customElements: How to get services destroy itself when customElements is removed from DOM?

Tags: angular, custom-element

I have 2 Angular projects. The first project which will be built as a custom web element to be consumed by another project.

[Project A] - app.module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CustomModules
    ]
    providers: [
        MyService  <---- this did not get destroyed when <custom-element> was removed from DOM
        ...
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
    ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
        if (environment.mode=== 'production') {
           customElements.define('custom-element', createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector: this.injector }));
        }
    }
}
```

[Project B] - app.component.html:

Contains `<*ngIf="..." custom-element></custom-element>` to display the whole of Project A.

However, when I remove the custom-element from DOM (using ngIf or display:none), `MyService` OnDestroy method did not get called since it was provided in Project A app.module.

- I tried providing `MyService` in AppComponent providers which allows OnDestroy to be called but i am not able to use the same service in my CustomModules in Project A, since it wasn't provided in root (app.module).

How can I provide `MyService` to both `AppComponent` and `CustomModules` and also ensure that MyService OnDestroy gets called when custom-elements was removed from DOM?

Answer (score 1):

In your Project B, use the Injector class to create an instance of MyService, then bind this instance into your custom element as an Input:

**[Project B] - app.component.html**

```js
myServiceInstance : any
constructor (..., this.injector: Injector) {
...
this.myServiceInstance = this.injector.get(MyService)
}
```

**[Project A (Custom Element)] - app.component.ts**

```js
...
@Input() serviceInstance: any;
...
// user serviceInstance like you use your normal service
```

With this I would expect the service instance to be destroy parallel with the custom component.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, `MyService` must remain in Project A. I am restricted to move the service into Project B.